# Karaf w/ LDAP Auth

Tags: authentication, ldap, apache-karaf, jaas

I'm trying to setup karaf (4.0.9) to authenticate/authorize users via ldap/active directory.

I've copied the following ldap-module.xml to the deploy directory per https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_available_realm_and_login_modules:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:jaas="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0">

  <jaas:config name="karaf" rank="1">
    <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule" flags="sufficient">
      initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
      connection.username=cn=ldapsearch,cn=users,dc=eng,dc=net
      connection.password=****
      connection.protocol=
      connection.url=ldap://server:389
      user.base.dn=dc=eng,dc=net
      user.filter=(samaccountname=%u)
      user.search.subtree=true
      user.debug=true
      role.base.dn=dc=eng,dc=net
      role.name.attribute=cn
      role.filter=(member=%fqdn)
      role.search.subtree=true
      role.mapping=jtAdmins=admin,user,operator
      authentication=simple
      debug=true
    </jaas:module>
  </jaas:config>

</blueprint>
```

I see the logs, and I can see the LDAP login on the realm, so I'm confident the config is at least being used

```
karaf@root(jaas)> jaas:realm-list
Index | Realm Name | Login Module Class Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule
```

When I try to ssh in, I get the following logs (truncated), and I can see shark the LDAP communications:

```
2017-07-31 16:50:39,229 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Get the user DN.
2017-07-31 16:50:39,238 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Looking for the user in LDAP with 
2017-07-31 16:50:39,238 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 |   base DN: dc=eng,dc=net
2017-07-31 16:50:39,238 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 |   filter: (samaccountname=jtAdmin)
2017-07-31 16:50:39,244 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Found the user DN.
2017-07-31 16:50:39,245 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Bind user (authentication).
2017-07-31 16:50:39,245 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Set the security principal for CN=jtAdmin,CN=Users,dc=eng,dc=net
2017-07-31 16:50:39,245 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Binding the user.
2017-07-31 16:50:39,254 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | User jtAdmin successfully bound.
2017-07-31 16:50:39,256 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Looking for the user roles in LDAP with 
2017-07-31 16:50:39,256 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 |   base DN: dc=eng,dc=net
2017-07-31 16:50:39,256 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 |   filter: (member=CN=jtAdmin,CN=Users,DC=eng,DC=net)
2017-07-31 16:50:39,359 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | User jtAdmin is a member of role Domain Computers
2017-07-31 16:50:39,359 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Parse role mapping jtAdmin=admin,user,operator
2017-07-31 16:50:39,359 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Parse role mapping jtAdmin=admin,user,operator
2017-07-31 16:50:39,359 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | User jtAdmin is a member of role Domain Controllers
```

...

```
2017-07-31 16:50:39,364 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Parse role mapping jtAdmins=admin,user,operator
2017-07-31 16:50:39,364 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | Parse role mapping jtAdmins=admin,user,operator
2017-07-31 16:50:39,364 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | LDAP role jtAdmins is mapped to Karaf role admin
2017-07-31 16:50:39,364 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | LDAP role jtAdmins is mapped to Karaf role user
2017-07-31 16:50:39,365 | DEBUG | 8]-nio2-thread-9 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 35 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.9 | LDAP role jtAdmins is mapped to Karaf role operator
```

I can see LDAP authorize my user, but it seems I don't have permission to login.  I thought the role.mapping would handle mapping my LDAP/AD membership to Karaf roles, but that doesn't seem to allow me access.  Webconsole also attempts to allow access, but ultimately fails.

What config am I missing to map the LDAP/AD user roles to enable ssh  karaf/console for my user?  Do I need another login module?  And how might I do this dynamically (not using hard-coded role.mapping in the ldap-module.xml bundle)?

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to give ldap OR local users access simultaneously, but I realize that might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

As luck would have it, I managed to track down the root cause.  Thanks to the folks on the karaf IRC channel that let me think out loud.

Ultimately, I believe the root cause is this exception:

```
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name ...
```

I only actually see this exception in the webconsole handler, and NOT in the ssh/shell handler (but ssh doesn't work either, so...)

The exception is coming from LDAPCache.java (namingEnumeration.hasMore(), ~line 259) and ultimately from

```
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2914)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888)
```

This exception is propagated to the caller.  Since I can't very well change the JVM, I'm borrowing a suggestions/solution of adding a config option to ignorePartialNameResult regarding this exception.  I don't quite understand why there is a partial name result, but I saw one comment implying that the error was due to role.base.dn being the same level as the user.base.dn which is true in my case.  After catching the exception, and returning the existing roleList, I am able to successfully login w/ ldap users.